# Android DefaultSharedPreference retains value after file deletion

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

```
long t = System.currentTimeMillis();
SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sp.edit();
editor.putLong("CurrentTime", t);
editor.apply();
File f = new File("/data/data/<mypackage>/shared_prefs/<mypackage>_preferences.xml");
boolean b = f.delete();
if (b == false)
    Trace.i("Hello", "we did not delete it");
else
    Trace.i("Hello", "we deleted it");
Trace.i("Hello","Reading" +Long.toString(sp.getLong("CurrentTime", 0)));
```

The logs are :

```
I/Hello : We deleted it
I/Hello : Reading 1482471022197
```

So the expected outcome should be **Reading 0**, what am I doing wrong here ?

Answer (score 0):

You deleted your File not shared preferences. To get to know about how shared Preferences work go through this basic tutorial : https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_shared_preferences.htm

Comment: Are shared preferences not stored in a xml file ?

Comment: If I deleted the file which the shared preference interface reads to extract the value , then how am I getting a non default value in case of read?

Comment: @VinaySharma go through my answer's link you will get to know how shared preferences work and how you can make operations on them.

Answer (score 0):

Shared preferences are fetched from the file when you create an instance of `SharedPreferences`. So the values are cached in the memory. So if you delete the file, values are still cached. To take affect of deleting `SharedPreferences` file, you need to re-create instance of `SharedPreferences`

Comment: Are you sure about this, I created a different object of sharedPreference and am getting the same value.

Comment: @VinaySharma, I was sure before, but not now :-) Deleting file manually is not a good idea in general. Am I right, that you want to clear SharedPreferences?

Comment: Yes I know. This question came out of curosity.

Comment: @VinaySharma, there are some .bak (backup) files sometimes for shared prefs. So they might get restored from those files.

Comment: Yes, the existence of backup files looks like a plausible explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Do not Delete SharedPreferences file.

Instead of this try below code:

```
sp.edit().clear();
sp.edit().commit();
```